# GPU render crashing

Tags: gpu

i got new machine recently.
CPU ryzen 3950x, 64GB of ram on 3200 MHz
and xfx RX 5700 thic III ultra radeon graphics card.
Whenever i try to render By GPU it crashing. No matter which version of blender i use 2.80 and up result is the same. As soon as I activate it edit/pref./system/open CL
and under render change CPU for GPU computing program crashes. Does anyone know what is going on. Btw I reinstaled drivers for graphics. No other result.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering down your tile render, ex 32x32. It must be a driver tdrdelay issue.
Post here wheter it worked or not